# How to initialize a pointer of type Superclass with a Subclass object?

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize a pointer in the following way:

```
Space* a = new GO();
```

where `GO` is a subclass of `Space`.
This is my code:

**Space.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    
class Space
{
protected:
std::string name;
    
public:
Space ();
Space (std::string new_name);
std::string get_name ();
};
```

**Space.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Space.h"
Space::Space(){}
Space::Space(std::string new_name):
    name(new_name){}

std::string Space::get_name() {
    return name;
}
```

**GO.h**

```
#include "Space.h"
class GO:public Space{
  public:
  GO();
};
```

**GO.cpp**

```
#include "GO.h"
GO::GO()
    :Space("Go")
{}
```

I'm getting the errors:

> expected type-specifier before 'GO'
>
> cannot convert 'int*' to Space*' in initialization
>
> expected ',' or ';' before 'GO'

How do I fix these errors? Is there a better way to declare a pointer like this?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and [edit] your question to include it. Without that, the best you're going to get is a bunch of guesses.

Comment: Application, as shown, compiles just fine for me.

Comment: You've shown us the context, which is good, but you did not show us the file that triggers the error. (By the way, does that file try to declare an object of type `GO`? That really should be attempted before you assume the problem lies with the pointer. Build things up; make sure `GO test;` works, then move on to `GO * g` and finally to `Space * a`.)

Comment: Do you have `#include "GO.h"` in the source file that contains `new GO()`?